# How do I truncate/restrict/limit the length of bytearray in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, byte, string-length

Let's say I have a bytearray of length 50 (50 bytes) but I want only the first 25 bytes from the bytearray. How do I do that?

For example:

`c = bytearray(b'1703020030f19322e5cc9b9e56cb71d2ebcd888582913f7f13')`

or

`` d= bytearray(b'\x17\x03\x03\x000\xd9O\x8a\x08L\t\x05:\xf6\xa0\x0b\xc0\xb6\xcc\xf5\x1a\xc5S\xf9\x98\xf4\\gTf\xcco\xc7\x10\x16\x1f\xf5\xcd`\x9f=K.\x8aj\x0b]\x9eW\xd0\x04\x17\xcd') ``

`len(c) = 50` and `len(d) = 53`.

How do I just extract the first 50 bytes of it and discard the rest?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"I want only the first 25 bytes from the bytearray"_: What's wrong with good old `c[:25]`?

Comment: try this c=c[:25]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bytearray is a sequence, so you can just slice it:

```
d = d[:50]
```

Or, to avoid unnecessary copies if performance is critical and the bytearray will usually be shorter than your limit:

```
if len(d) > 50:
    d = d[:50]
```

Comment: I have a "special case", where a library used in ctypes interface returns data with size increments of 4, and the caller may want to get a bytearray size of something else. e.g. 1024 * 1024 + 2 where I'd have to prepare buffer of 1024 * 1024 + 4... returning slice would be a bit heavy operation, but I saw. ba.pop(); ba.pop() to do the trick. id(ba), ba.__alloc__() and ba.__sizeof__() returned the same before and after the pop()s